# 2D movement how to fix?

Tags: game-engine, godot

I asked this question before and got a answer but that  answer didnt work nor did the guy respond so here is my last effort, The kinematic body isnt moving yes i added controls to the project setting, yes there are no errors. I dont know what to do. `

```
Extends KinematicBody2D
var movespeed = 500

func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.
func _physics_process(delta):
    var motion = Vector2()

    if Input.is_action_pressed("up"):
        motion.y -= 1
        if Input.is_action_pressed("down"):
            motion.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        motion.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        motion.x -= 1

    motion = motion.normalized()
```

``

Comment: Have you tried [move and slide](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody.html#class-kinematicbody-method-move-and-slide)? It would narrow the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a Vector called `motion` and set it's values, however you never actually do anything with that data.

It's best to use something like [move and slide](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody.html#class-kinematicbody-method-move-and-slide) to alter the position of a kinematic body.

However, using what you have, you can add your motion values to the `global_transform` of the node which would have a similar effect.